# In Android, How can i stretch EditText until it meet some view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have some problem in my layout width edit-text

here are screenshots which describe my problem

**1. normal layout (all views are inside the *LinearLayout*)**

[image]

**2. I want layout below when user input many text lines inside the Edit Text**

[image]

**3. But When user enter many text lines.. my layout looks like below.**

[image]

I want the Edit Text should be stretched until only ImageView meets the bottom ViewGroup.

but, more entering text lines, more being increased the height of Edit Text so, i cannot see Image View.

i'd appreciate it if you give me any solution.

Comment: check weights for LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` handles this sort of layouts great. You can use the attribute  `android:layout_weight="1"` within a `LinearLayout` to set the priority of the space you want the object to take.

The official documentation describe it best:
[developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

Answer (score 0):

Take RelativeLayout as your parent layout

```
   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
       android:id="@+id/view1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomGroup"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```